# Using JavaScript to change text on the page every half-second

Tags: javascript, html

So, what I'm hoping to do is change the text inside a set of `<p>` tags every half-second. The set of tags in question is in this block of code in my body:

```
<div class="outerdiv" id="col2">
    <p id="matrixText"></p>
</div>
```

Right below the above code I have the JavaScript that should call a function every half-second:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("changeMatrixText()", 500);
</script>
```

I have the function `changeMatrixText` defined inside my head:

```
function changeMatrixText()
{
    var newtext = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        newtext += Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1) % 2 ? "0" : "1";
    document.getElementById("matrixText").value = newtext;
}
```

As you see, that's supposed to set the text to a random string of 0's and 1's. But it's not working. Any idea why?

Just in case you need to see my entire code .....

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple encrypt/decrypt</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        body 
        {
            background-color: #A9F5F2;
            width: 900px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .outerdiv
        {
            margin: 5px;
            border: 2px solid #FF8000;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .outerdiv > p
        {
            margin: 5px;
            word-wrap:break-word
        }
        .outerdiv > h1
        {
            margin: 5px;
        }
        #col1
        {
            width: 500x;
            height: 800px;
            float: left;
        }
        #col2
        {
            width: 295px;
            height: 1500px;
            float: right;
            font-family: Courier New;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #title1div
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #insctdiv
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #iptdiv
        {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #buttonsdiv
        {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #inputText
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            resize: none;
        }

    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function encrypt()
        {
            var text = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
            newstring = "";
            /* Make newstring a string of the bit representations of 
               the ASCII values of its thisCharacters in order.
            */
            for (var i = 0, j = text.length; i < j; i++) 
            { 
                bits = text.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
                newstring += new Array(8-bits.length+1).join('0') + bits;
            }
            /* Compress newstring by taking each substring of 3, 4, ..., 9 
               consecutive 1's or 0's and it by the number of such consecutive
               thisCharacters followed by the thisCharacter. 
               EXAMPLES:
                    "10101000010111" --> "10101401031"
                    "001100011111111111111" --> "0011319151"
            */
            newstring = newstring.replace(/([01])\1{2,8}/g, function($0, $1) { return ($0.length + $1);});      
            document.getElementById("inputText").value = newstring;
        }

        function decrypt()
        {
            var text = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
            text = text.trim();
            text.replace(/([2-9])([01])/g,
            function (all, replacementCount, bit) {
                return Array(+replacementCount + 1).join(bit);
            }).split(/(.{8})/g).reduce(function (str, byte) {
                return str + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 2));
            }, "");
            document.getElementById("inputText").value = text;
        }


        function changeMatrixText()
        {
            var newtext = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                newtext += Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1) % 2 ? "0" : "1";
            document.getElementById("matrixText").value = newtext;
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="col1">
        <div class="outerdiv" id="title1div">
            <h1>Reversible text encryption algorithm</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="outerdiv" id="insctdiv">
            <p>Type in or paste text below, then click <b>Encrypt</b> or <b>Decrypt</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="outerdiv" id="iptdiv">
            <textarea id="inputText" scrolling="yes"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="outerdiv" id="buttonsdiv">
            <button onclick="encrypt()"><b>Encrypt</b></button>
            <button onclick="decrypt()"><b>Decrypt</b></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outerdiv" id="col2">
        <p id="matrixText"></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval("changeMatrixText()", 500);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In essence, I'm trying to make the right column of my page keep printing inside a new string of 0's and 1's every half-second, kinda like on the computer screen on the movie *The Matrix*, if you catch my drift.

Comment: A paragraph has no value ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("matrixText").innerHTML = newtext;`

Comment: Also don't set the interval timer that way - do this: `setInterval(changeMatrixTest, 500);`

Comment: It looks a whole bunch of people all had the same idea... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes), the elements with a value attribute include `<button>`, `<option>`, `<input>`, `<li>`, `<meter>`, `<progress>`, and `<param>`. You'll need to set the `innerHTML` instead.

```
document.getElementById("matrixText").value = newtext;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("matrixText").innerHTML = newtext;
```

and

```
setInterval("changeMatrixText()", 500);
```

to

```
setInterval(changeMatrixText, 500);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3r93N/embedded/result/)**

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("matrixText").value = newtext;
```

.value is used for form fields instead use

```
document.getElementById("matrixText").innerHTML = newtext;
```

in your changeMatrixText function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the setInterval method to accept the first argument as the function itself (the name, minus the parentheses), rather than a string...

As you are not passing any parameters explicitly, you can invoke the function as follows:

```
setInterval(changeMatrixText, 500);
```

Should you have needed to supply some parameters, then the following would work:

```
setInterval(function() {
  changeMatrixText(myParam1, myParam2); // etc, etc
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/35W4Z/

The main difference is that a `<p>` element doesn't have a `.value` attribute. Instead, use the `innerHTML` attribute (as shown in the JSFiddle example)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well for fun, I stuck this in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdmA5/1/

So two things, mostly:

1) You can't set the "value" of a div element. You have to set the `.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("matrixText").innerHTML = newtext;
```

2) This could be due to the fact I built this out in fiddle, but setInterval is notorious for not running like you expect unless you give each iteration its own memory space. I did this by wrapping the call to changeMatrix in a anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function() {changeMatrixText();}, 500);
```

Check out the jsfiddle link to see it in action.